# Find element based on 2 attributes

Tags: jquery

I would like to change my `span` background only where the attribute `data-id` is `attrac-2` and also where `data-pos="1"`

How can I find element base on two attributes?

```
<div class="well dropZone" id="sec12">                  
  <div class="panel panel-info attrac ui-widget-content fadeSec" data-id="attrac-2" data-pos="1">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <span class="pull-right"></span>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery selectors follow CSS rules, so just use two attribute selectors without a space between them. See the duplicate for more information

Comment: Thanks................ ................